# LaTeX and Google Drive Sync issues

Tags: texshop

I use Google Drive to access my files across multiple devices.  I also like to link directly to Google Drive files (providing a shareable link to files) so that I can update the file without having to re-upload the document every time I make a change to a file.  Occasionally, when I update the file from one computer versus another, multiple TeX files get created for the same project, and the link breaks for a LaTeX file.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Both computers are Macs running macOS Sierra (10.12.4), and I'm using TeXShop (vs 3.77).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was being caused by using different computers on a campus network and on a private network.  Accessing the campus network has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- As far as I know, Dropbox handles this kind of task better.
- When I was facing the problem (even with Dropbox, large project) then I used the following approach.

---

1. Starting the PC.
2. Let the software sync the files.
3. Disable syncing by stopping Dropbox or by disabling it.
4. Work on the project until I finish it.
5. Start the sync again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Dropbox has been disallowed from my university due to security concerns (I used Dropbox previously). This seems to be an idiosyncrasy I'll just have to live with for now.

Comment: @JavaMan The approach I use is not limited to Dropbox. Just do the same (pause sync OR just exit it) with Google Drive.

Comment: I understand.  I suspect that turning sync on and off is a surefire way (for me) to make sure I lose access to some files on a machine.  Nonetheless thank you for your comments and your help.